# Please undelete my answer

Tags: support, status-completed, deleted-answers, specific-answer, undelete-request

As per the advice at [How does deleting work? What can cause a post to be deleted, and what does that actually mean? What are the criteria for deletion?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5221/how-does-deleting-work-what-can-cause-a-post-to-be-deleted-and-what-does-that) I would like to politely ask if anyone could vote to undelete my answer to this question: [How to submit a straightforward form using Angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20624772/how-to-submit-a-straightforward-form-using-angular)

The answer I gave completely documented the solution to the problem I originally posed. The only other answer posted was not sufficient, as per the comments left in response to that one, and was significantly different to the approach I ultimately took. It seems to me that several contributors saw that my answer began with the word "thanks" and decided that was sufficient to qualify it for deletion.

Comment: I don't see it as deleted. I see it as having (as of the time of this comment) two downvotes, which is not "deleted".

Comment: @KenWhite It *was* deleted when this question was posted. Seems the OP got his request granted.

Comment: Related: [Review queues encourage deletion of non-answers that should be converted to comments](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/212544)

Comment: @GenericHolidayName: Yes, it does. Pretty quickly, too - must be either the meta effect or the holiday season. :-)

Comment: I just wish I could decline all those flags that got auto-dismissed as helpful when it was deleted... Ergh...